# How to handle Custombutton CheckedAnduncheck functionality in collectionviewcell in objective c with multiselection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I want collectionview cell in which i placed custom button checkboxes used for adding member to the group.multiselection is also possible.but when i select particular checkbox alongwith it the other checkbox which is not visible is also selected which is at same indexpath from lastvisible cell below is my code 
`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 CGCell *cell = [_CGCol dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckUncheckFunctionality:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
}
-(void)CheckUncheckFunctionality:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.selected) {
      [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare global Array and inititlize

```
NSMutableArray * ArrCheckIndexs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<no.ofcell; i++)
{
    [ArrCheckIndexs addObject:@"0"];
} 

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 CGCell *cell = [_CGCol dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(CheckUncheckFunctionality:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
} 


-(void)CheckUncheckFunctionality:(id)sender
  {
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
   if ([[ArrCheckIndexs objectAtIndex:btn.tag] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
      [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [ArrCheckIndexs replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:@"0"];
    }
  else
  {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [ArrCheckIndexs replaceObjectAtIndex:btn.tag withObject:@"1"];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Kajal Same problem when i select the button at index 3 the other button which is after last visiblecell on index 3 will be automatically checked i got correct index still d problem . pls help@Kajal

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Give condition in cellForItemAtIndex Function also

Comment: This is the condition:
if ([[ArrCheckIndexs objectAtIndex:btn.tag] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
      [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
  else
  {
       [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }

Comment: Check the button tag and set the button tag before addTarget line

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Did you find the solution?

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Use debugger in cellForItemAt Index and check when condition is not satisfied

Comment: Done Somewhat it helps....but now problem is with Searching when i search index always first cell button is selected Thanx @iphone dev For Helping

Answer (score 1):

The cell might be getting reused. And Since you are not updating the cells when they are returned by the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`method they are in their last updated state. Solution : -

I presume you are using models for cell information

1. Add an boolean flag in the model which will store whether the item is checked or not. Initially false
2. When you will return the cell check for the model for the flag value for the cells. and update the button state accordingly.

Comment: I cannot edit your code. If you have any doubts you can ask. Its a simple solution. Just give it  a try

Comment: Are you even using model class for your cell?